Combining Vector Search and Geo Queries in Firestore in a Single Query?
Is there a way to combine vector search and geo queries in Firestore? If so, what would be the best approach or workaround to achieve this?

I don't know of any limitations around this combination. What isn't working about it when you try? Any error message?

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
